# Clojure test coverage tool?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

Hello fine StackOverFlow'ers,

I'm looking for a test coverage tool for my clojure project. Currently it's a pure clojure project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try [Radagast](http://github.com/technomancy/radagast).

Comment: This answer was probably a good answer back in 2010. Today Radagast has been unmaintained for 8 years. Consider Cloverage which is still active... or maybe something else :shrug:

Answer (score 8):

There is an another tool [cloverage](https://github.com/lshift/cloverage) which has now [Leningen](https://clojars.org/lein-cloverage/lein-cloverage) and preliminary [Boot](https://github.com/lshift/cloverage/pull/115) support.